# Crawling all comments on a website with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl all of the comments on a shopping website using Scrapy. I found this code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class deneme(CrawlSpider):
name = 'deneme'
allowed_domains = ['hepsiburada.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.hepsiburada.com/']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

This code crawls all of the website. But I would like to crawl only comments on the website and write them to a MongoDB database. I am not good at Python. How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class deneme(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'yorum'
    allowed_domains = ['hepsiburada.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.hepsiburada.com/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):




        print(response.xpath('//p[@class="review-text"]/text()').extract())
```

scrapy crawl yorum > output.txt

Comment: Are you answering your own question?